# Change Google Calendar Event Free/Busy with Calendar API

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, calendar, google-apis-explorer

I have a GAS web app for reserving rooms. When the app creates the event, it currently defaults to "Busy" for the event. I am trying to set the default to "Free".

I found a GAS forum entry that recommends using the Advanced Google Calendar API to edit the transparency field (Source: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2341).

The script they suggested was

```
var changes = {
transparency: "transparent"
};
Calendar.Events.patch(changes, cal_id, event_id);
```

I have the Advanced API enabled, but for some reason I am getting an uncaught error prompt in the Chrome console when the function executes. Any thoughts on where this error is coming from?

Comment: Did you enable the service in both the IDE and API console?

Comment: It is enabled in the API console and enabled in the Advanced Google Services window within Script Editor->Resources

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Not Found
 at reserve (Code:192) (AKTA Reservations) 6b308efd-2175-4681-a8fc-2f72e9160e6f

Comment: Line 192 is Calendar.Events.patch(changes, cal_id, event_id);

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking around, the following seems to work. I forgot that you need to remove the "@google.com" from the event ID returned by CalendarApp before making a request to CalendarApi. The calendarId can be set to 'primary' since the user is only editing an event on their own calendar

```
var eventId= event_id.slice(0,event_id.length-11);
var calendarId = 'primary';
Logger.log(eventId)
var changes = {
    transparency: "transparent"
  };
Calendar.Events.patch(changes,calendarId,eventId);
```