# create a "free" event in Google Calendar (instead of the default "busy")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

Im using the following script to create calender events from a list of dates on a google sheet.

```
function CreateEvent() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange('E4').getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  //var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("A8:C12").getValues();
  var lr = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  var count = spreadsheet.getRange("A8:F"+lr+"").getValues();

  for (x=0; x<count.length; x++) {

      var shift = count[x];
      var summary = shift[0];
      var startTime = shift[1];
      var endTime = shift[2];
      var guests = shift[3];
      //var description = shift[4];
      //var location = shift[5];

      var myEvent = eventCal.createEvent(summary, startTime, endTime, {transparency: 'transparent'});
      var myEventId = myEvent.getId();
      var myEventId = myEventId.slice(0,myEventId.length-11);

      spreadsheet.getRange("F8").offset(x, 0).setValue(myEventId);

      //makeEventFree(calendarId, myEventId);

  }
}
```

I'm trying to either create these events with the availability "free" instead of "busy" or to change the event to "free" after the creation.
The following proposal does not work anymore:
[Change Google Calendar Event Free/Busy with Calendar API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538997/change-google-calendar-event-free-busy-with-calendar-api)

Any ideas or proposals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to be accessing the Calendar api (under Special Services in app scripts). Once the event is accessed through the special service, your code should look very similar to what's listed in the shared example.

```
var changes = {
    transparency: "transparent"
  };
// This is the point where the api is accessed and your changes submitted.
Calendar.Events.patch(changes,calendarId,eventId);
```

Comment: Strange ... Your proposal is the same as the one in the link I mentioned already and this did not work some weeks ago! - Anyway! Thanks! Today it worked immediately!