# Define calenderID for Google API Calendar.Events.patch

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, calendar

I tried to update Google Calender events with the following code from
[Change Google Calendar Event Free/Busy with Calendar API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538997/change-google-calendar-event-free-busy-with-calendar-api)

```
var eventId= event_id.slice(0,event_id.length-11);
var calendarId = 'primary';
Logger.log(eventId)
var changes = {
    transparency: "transparent"
  };
Calendar.Events.patch(changes,calendarId,eventId);
```

I don't want to patch events in my primary calender, but all events in my birhtday reminder calender (i sync all birthdays from my contacts to this calender), so i tried a bit around without success.

I tried:

```
var calendarId = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("example@group.calendar.google.com")
var calendarId = 'example@group.calendar.google.com'
var calendarId = 'example'
```

Nothing worked. I always got:

```
ReferenceError: Calendar is not defined
```

Anybody has an idea how this works with other calenders, than primary?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a reference error, I think it has to do with the missing global class `Calendar` as used in the referenced question.

This issue can be solved by enabling the [advanced calendar service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) before use as shown [here](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web_development/9781785882517/5/ch05lvl1sec54/enabling-advanced-google-services) (please note this uses the old editor, which you can toggle to temporarily from the UI if you're using the recent one).

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get calendar id's:

```
function displayCalendarInfo() {
  var cals=CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
  var s='Calendar Information';
  for(var i=0;i<cals.length;i++) {
    s+=Utilities.formatString('<br />Name: %s Id: %s', cals[i].getName(),cals[i].getId());
  }
  s+='<br /><input type="button" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s).setWidth(1200).setHeight(450);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Calendar Data');
}
```

Comment: Is there any difference to the calendar ID I see in the Web UI under settings? Is there a second ID that is different? 
For the sync from contacts to my custom calendar I need the ID and that is working. Same ID for the Calendar.events.patch doesn't work. That's what confused me.

Comment: There is no second id, you should be able to use the calendar id in the web ui. This `var calendarId = 'example@group.calendar.google.com'` should work. The problem is that as mentioned by @Abdellah Hariti, `Calendar` object is not defined. You need to enabled Advanced Calendar Service to use `Calendar` object