# How can I specify free/busy when creating an event on Google Calendar using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am working on a time-off request form using Google Apps Script. The idea is to generate a live Google Form for users to complete, the answers to which are recorded in a Google Sheet. If the request is approved, then a notification is sent via email and events are created on Google Calendar.

The problem arises when I try to create the Calendar events: The approved time off needs to be created as all-day events on one calendar, but the events need to be set to Free (as opposed to Busy) to avoid any conflict with other users' time off.

Here's what I have so far with regards to creating the actual event:

```
CalendarApp.getCalendarById(email)
   .createAllDayEvent(
      `${username} - Time Off`,
      startDate,
      endDate,
      {
         description: message,
         guests: additionalEmails,
         sendInvites: true
      });
```

I have searched extensively through the Google Apps Script documentation on its Calendar service, but have found no mention to setting free/busy setting when creating an event.

The closest solution I am able to find after spending considerable time searching is [this question from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538997/change-google-calendar-event-free-busy-with-calendar-api). However, I am unable to find a lot of context surrounding both that question and the answer, and searching Google's documentation on the advanced Calendar API hasn't helped at all either.

I would be surprised to discover that Google Apps Script does not include some built-in option(s) that allow(s) users to specify free/busy when creating Calendar events, so I hope there is some relatively simple solution or workaround. Apologies in advance if I am missing something very obvious, as I am a relative newbie to Google Apps Script.

Let me know if any more information is needed or if anything needs clarification. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have found the solution. In your Apps Script File add the [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced). Then when after creating the event you can modify it used the advanced Calendar API as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42585196/9418616